# Fixing 'The underlying provider failed on Open.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

My application fills dbcontext with some data - this takes very long time (approx. 14-20 hours). If the GetWorskpace() method gets data succesfully, then method DeleteModel.DeleteModelInDb() is called - this method deletes all the data in the DB. After delete dbcontext is saved with new data.

I'm getting following error on this line of code

```
DeleteModel.DeleteModelInDb(del);
```

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider
>   failed on Open.' TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout

and

> TransactionException: The operation is not valid for the state of the
>   transaction.

My code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        PdmContext db = new PdmContext();

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");

        Application pdApplication = new Application();
        PdWSP.Workspace pdWorkspace = (PdWSP.Workspace)pdApplication.ActiveWorkspace;
        pdWorkspace.Load("H:\\workspace_dummy.sws");

        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new System.TimeSpan(100, 0, 0))) //100 hours            
        {
            GetWorkspace((pdWorkspace as PdWSP.WorkspaceFolder), db); //fills dbcontext - takes about 14 hours


            using (var del = new PdmContext())
                {
                    DeleteModel.DeleteModelInDb(del);

                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                scope.Complete();
        }          

        db.Dispose();

    }
```

My DeleteModelInDb class:

```
public static class DeleteModel
{
    public static void DeleteModelInDb(PdmContext del)
    {

        string nspace = "PdmExporter.Models";
        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == nspace

                select t;

        var list = q.ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            items.Add("dbo.[" + item.Name + "]");
        }


        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            del.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table " + i + ";"); 
            del.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('" + i + "', RESEED, 1)");
        }
        del.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant keep a dbcontext open like this, instead fill your structures and at the last moment open a new context and attach\add to it

Comment: `PdmContext db = new PdmContext();` leaves the context open while `using` statement reached, and you can't reuse same context in a single transaction scope for both `SELECT` and `DELETE` operations. You need to close existing transaction scope before initiating another one.

Comment: You don't need `TransactionScope`. `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally. Make any modifications you need *without* calling `SaveChanges` eg in ` DeleteModelInDb` and only call `SaveChanges` once, when you want the changes to be stored

Comment: `fills dbcontext - takes about 14 hours` why are you using an ORM for  ETL jobs in the first place then? EF isn't a replacement for ADO.NET and it's certainly not meant for such operations. Most likely, using multiple contexts with transactions results in each context blocking the others. As for the `truncate/reseed` pair, these have no place in ORM code and suggest a strange design too.

Comment: @TheGeneral -as I stated - the method that fills the structures runs for about 14 hourse and it fills about 25 tables. So should I create list for every table and at the end open context and fill it from the lists?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - reason why I am using TransactionScope is because when my data fails to load I don't want the old data to be deleted.

Comment: @xcelm don't use separate contexts then. Or don't use an ORM in the first place. An ORM's job is to map entities to tables, not replace SQL. Maintenance operations like what `DeleteModelInDb` is trying to do are unsuitable and risky

Comment: @xcelm in any case, without knowing what your code does, we can't help. 14 hours is definitely a strong smell unless you work with multiple TB of data